# Array not acting as expected in jQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, ajax

I'm doing jQuery Ajax with PHP, and after jQuery passes some $_POST data to PHP, PHP validates those data, and prepares an array with all the errors, and once all validation is done, the count of error is found, and if it is greater than 0, the array is encoded in json and it is printed on the screen. jQuery then grabs those data with 'success:' and it does it, but it doesn't act as expected.

PHP file validating:

```
<?php
$messages = array();

if(isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['subject']) && isset($_POST['message'])) {
    if(empty($_POST['name'])) {
        $messages[] = "Please fill in the Name field.";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['email'])) {
        $messages[] = "Please fill in the Email field.";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['subject'])) {
        $messages[] = "Please fill in the Subject field.";
    }
    if(empty($POST['message'])) {
        $messages[] = "Please write your message in the Message field!";
    }

    if(!filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $messages[] = "Invalid email entered!";
    }

    if(strlen($_POST['name']) > 30 || strlen($_POST['name']) < 3) {
        $messages[] = "Your name cannot be less than 3 characters or more than 30 characters.";
    }
    if(strlen($_POST['email']) > 30 || strlen($_POST['email']) < 3) {
        $messages[] = "Your email cannot be less than 3 characters or more than 30 characters.";
    }
    if(strlen($_POST['subject']) > 30 || strlen($_POST['subject']) < 3) {
        $messages[] = "The subject cannot be less than 3 characters or more than 30 characters.";
    }
    if(strlen($_POST['message']) > 2000 || strlen($_POST['message']) < 40) {
        $messages[] = "Your message cannot be less than 40 characters or more than 2000 characters.";
    }

    if(count($messages) > 0) {
        $messages['elements'] = count($messages);
        echo json_encode($messages);
    } else {

    }
}
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $(document).on('click', '.contact_submit', function() {
        var name = $('input#name').val();
        var email = $('input#email').val();
        var subject = $('input#subject').val();
        var message = $('input#message').val();

        var Data = "name=" + name + "&email=" + email + "&subject=" + subject + "&message=" + message;

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "portal/_inc/frontend/form.php",
            data: Data,
            success: function(messages) {

                var Count = messages.length;
                $('.messages').empty();
                for(var i = 0; i < Count; i++) {
                    $('.messages').append('<li class"error">' + messages[i] + '</li>\n');
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

All works fine, but my output is in 'char' format like one character at a time. [Click here for a screen shot.](http://prntscr.com/4fm5in)

Comment: you are not decoding the return `messages = $.parseJSON(messages);`

Comment: @bansi doing that breaks my click event.. it doesn't do anything now..

Comment: When I alert the messages array, it says [object Object]

Comment: what is the alert for messages before parse json?

Comment: This is the message before parsing: http://prntscr.com/4fmcaz

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add `dataType:'JSON'` to your ajax request:

```
 $.ajax({
        dataType:'JSON',
        type: "POST",
        url: "portal/_inc/frontend/form.php",
        data: Data,
        .....
```

and add

```
 header('Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
```

to your php so that the javascript knows how to handle the response

**EDIT**

the problem is that the json response is an object, not array, which does not have a `.length` property.

you'd be better to do it like this:

```
success: function(messages) {
      $('.messages').empty();
      $.each(messages,function(){
           $('.messages').append('<li class"error">' + this + '</li>\n');
               });
        }
```

Comment: still no luck. It is not showing any messages to me.

Comment: Error I get: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for '528' in {"0":"Please fill in the Name field.","1":"Please fill in the Email field.","2":"Please fill in the Subject field.","3":"Please write your message in the Message field!","4":"Inval...<omitted>...9}

Comment: It says that the error is in the jQuery.js file (Which has the jQuery lib)

Comment: yeah, ok I found the same error as you now, adding `dataType:'JSON'` ,as stated in my original post, which someone down voted, fixes your issue

Answer (score 2):

It's because your response is a string, and you're iterating over a string.

This PHP code:

```
echo json_encode($messages);
```

encodes an object/array into a JSON string.

And this JS code:

```
var Count = messages.length;
```

will just return the length of the whole string, not the number of individual objects within the returned JSON.

---

The simplest way to fix it is to parse the JSON in your success callback:

```
var messageObject = JSON.parse(messages);
```

and now the variable `messageObject` will have the data in the format you expected.

Comment: err, it still didn't fix my problem.

Comment: It says [object Object] when I alert the messages array after parsing it.

Comment: That's normal when you try to alert an object. Since JSON.parse returns an object, try doing the `for (var i in messages)` loop instead. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/9hbqobvv/